# Plotting AIC for intermediate and optimal ARIMA(p,d,q)

Tags: r, plot, arima

After the optimisation algorithm used to find out the best ARIMA(p,d,q) model, according to minimisation of AIC, I also get the following:

`head()`:

```
  d p q       AIC
1 0 0 0 -2671.744
2 0 0 1 -2686.691
3 0 0 2 -2685.053
4 0 0 3 -2683.094
5 0 0 4 -2688.464
6 0 0 5 -2686.973
```

`tail()`:

```
   d p q       AIC
31 0 5 0 -2685.982
32 0 5 1 -2684.926
33 0 5 2 -2683.003
34 0 5 3 -2683.654
35 0 5 4 -2686.069
36 0 5 5 -2698.871
```

where, yes, d=0 everywhere.

I was wondering whether someone knows how to plot (3d surface or even 2d) the different combinations in order to visualise the improvements in terms of AIC. Might be cool also to highlight the max AIC somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of visualization you want exactly, but a heatmap seems appropriate. Here's one in `ggplot2`. I made `p` and `q` into factors, and from there just used a `geom_raster` to make tiles.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- "dummy d p q       AIC
1 0 0 0 -2671.744
2 0 0 1 -2686.691
3 0 0 2 -2685.053
4 0 0 3 -2683.094
5 0 0 4 -2688.464
6 0 0 5 -2686.973" %>% read_table2()

d2 <- "dummy    d p q       AIC
31 0 5 0 -2685.982
32 0 5 1 -2684.926
33 0 5 2 -2683.003
34 0 5 3 -2683.654
35 0 5 4 -2686.069
36 0 5 5 -2698.871" %>% read_table2()

df <- bind_rows(d1, d2) %>% 
    select(-dummy) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(p, q), as.factor)

ggplot(df, aes(x = p, y = q, fill = AIC)) +
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "A")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: thank you for your help. If I have yet a `df` how can I modify the code? I don't need actually to rbind `d1` and `d2` since these two were just the `head` and `tail` fo the data frame.

Comment: Sure, just use your data frame. I had to do that to put together the data you provided